# Прикладывать или прилагать?

Tags: вид, стиль

Фраза "Повезло выучить второй язык, не прикладывая усилий" режет мне слух. Я бы написал "Повезло выучить второй язык, не прилагая усилий". Я прав? Это стилистика? Или действительно ошибка? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобный вопрос был задан на [грамоте.ру](http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_474400). Ответ такой:

> Правильно: **прилагать усилия**. С глаголом совершенного вида приложить в значении 'направить действие чего-л. на что-л., применить' соотносится глагол несовершенного вида прилагать.

Answer (score 1):

Ну стилистически сочетание "прилагать усилия" выглядит, конечно, лучше, так как глагол "прикладывать" ассоциируется с физическим действием. Однако "прикладывать усилия" также весьма распространённый оборот, и, если и есть какое-то правило, которое запрещает его использовать, лучше на него не ссылаться, а то прослывёшь пуристом, а то и, не дай Бог, граммар-наци ;-)